# Is there a way to create a generic repository not related to a specific class in Symfony 4?

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I'm upgrading my old Symfony 2.7 code base to Symfony 4 and I have some Dao classes that don't fit in a specific class repository.

For example: I have a Dao that gives me generic database info like counting the total of records in every table and other that accesses mostly database functions that do several operations.

Is there a way to create a repository that isn't related to a specific class ? If not what is the most "Symfony 4" way of creating this ?

I thought maybe in creating a separate Dao class which is not a repository, inject EntityManager in it and put all the queries there. Is there a better way of doing this ?

**EDIT**: Can anyone please comment on why this question is not being answered ? Am I missing something here ? I'm thinking in raising the bounty after this one expires but I'm unsure to do this and just loose rep without any answer.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, the data you want to retrieve isn't related to any specific entity, so you won't ever need repository functions such as findBy, nor won't you need to hydrate any entity, and you probably won't need to use any DQL either.

So what your suggestion seems correct to me : inject entity manager inside a class, that you could call DatabaseMetadataRepository for exampel, even if it doesn't extend ServiceEntityRepository. Then just put your requests, with native queries if necessary :

```php
class DatabaseMetadataRepository
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function loadMetadata($someParameter) {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

        $sql = "
            SELECT whatever
            FROM whatever_table t
            WHERE my_column = :someParameter
        ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array('someParameter' => $someParameter));
        return $stmt->fetchAll(\Doctrine\DBAL\FetchMode::COLUMN);
    }
}
```

Seems a legit approach to me.